# how to restore the original size after using the NERDTree Menu in Vim?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I use NERDTree as a file explorer and after using its Menu, Vim does not return to its original size, see screenshots below.

Using NERDTree Menu:
[image]

After using the Menu:
[image]

The editor returns to normal only if I resize the terminal window.

**My system config**

- Vim-GTK3 9.0
- Terminal: Konsole
- Debian 11

**NERDTree Config**

- `nmap <Leader>nt :NERDTreeFind<CR>`
- `let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=1`
- `let NERDTreeShowHidden=1`
- `let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable = '▸'`
- `let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible = '▾'`
- `let g:NERDTreeIgnore = ['^node_modules$']`

Comment: For the past couple of weeks, I'm experiencing the same problem. Are you using a Night Owl theme?

Comment: http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/

Comment: @arantebw , I am using [Catppuccin](https://github.com/catppuccin/vim)

Comment: `:resize` in my main window is a manual workaround.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a same issue and I have remove vim v9 and install from source last v8 and it's work!
I don't know what is happen in 9 version vim with the bottom pane, but I have observe that vim v8 on my remote server have a perfect working.

UPD:
And I founded issue on the NERDTree repo with the issue:
https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/issues/1321

Comment: how did you install a v8 of vim?

Comment: @Dids are you using linux?

Comment: i'm using MacOs @AntonyChavez

Comment: It is a solution, but only a work-around. It would be preferred if the menu was the same but after closing it, cmd height resets.

Comment: i did not downgrade to v8 since homebrew only installs latest/stable release, instead i added this to my .vimrc config: let g:NERDTreeMinimalMenu=1

Comment: if you guys are using neovim i suggest downgrade to 0.7.2, higher version has the same issue

Comment: I have installed v8 from sources - https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.5172
But it was before that I founded nerdtree issue :) I think @Dids are right - for the solution you need install latest NERDTree version. NERDTree developers fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 3):

You can set cmdheight to 2 to solve the problem.
Add the following line into your .vimrc

`set cmdheight=2`

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an incompatibility between NERDTree and Vim 9.0.

You can fix it by applying [this hotfix](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/pull/1322/files) to your local copy of NERDTree.

Some alternatives:

- Add `let g:NERDTreeMinimalMenu=1` to your `.vimrc` to set menu to display in a single line
- Use a version of Vim earlier than the 9.0 release

See [issue #1321](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/issues/1321) in the NERDTree repo for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This problem remains relevant. To restore the window size, you can try these shortcuts:

- `Ctrl+w _`
- `Ctrl+w |`
- `Ctrl+w =`

Source: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Resize_splits_more_quickly